# Recyclerview adapted from Firestore not appearing on Fragment (with tabs)

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

My Recyclerview (which is loaded from Firestore) works if I load it on the activity.

I just added a TabLayout and a ViewPager to my ConstraintLayout:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/storeIDLayout"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST 1" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test 2" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

and moved out the RecyclerView to fragment.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_prodlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_addorders" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Question:**
In the activity, I have this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Where do I insert this in my fragment?

**2nd Question:**

My fragment is appears empty. If I uncomment the Textview (R.id.section_label) - the textview works fine. But the recyclerview does not show up. Any idea why?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_new_order, container, false);

        FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
        Query mQuery;
        AddOrderAdapter mAdapter;

        RecyclerView mAddOrderRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_prodlist);
        mAddOrderRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mQuery = mFirestore
                .collection("PROD")
                .document("TEST")
                .collection("Items")
                .orderBy("Name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        mAdapter = new AddOrderAdapter(mQuery, getActivity());

        mAddOrderRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Edited to include model:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class AddOrderProductList {
    private String Barcode;
    private String ImageURL;
    private String Name;
    private String Unit;

    public AddOrderProductList() {}

    public String getBarcode() {
        return Barcode;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return ImageURL;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return Unit;
    }

    public AddOrderProductList(String barcode, String imageURL, String name, String unit) {
        Barcode = barcode;
        ImageURL = imageURL;
        Name = name;
        Unit = unit;
    }
}
```

2nd Edit:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class AddOrderProductList {
    private String barcode;
    private String imageURL;
    private String name;
    private String unit;

    public AddOrderProductList() {}

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public AddOrderProductList(String barcode, String imageURL, String name, String unit) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Database Structure:

```
PROD -> TEST -> Items -> Document of items with fields:

"Barcode" - String
"Name" - String
"Unit" - String
"ImageURL" - String
```

Comment: can you show your pojo class ? also, are you using firebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: I'm not using firebaseRecyclerAdapter - I'm using Firestore with android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is very simple:

> Where do I insert this in my fragment?

As you did it in your activity class and it worked, do it also in your fragment class. Override both `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods and start/stop listening for changes. Also, in the `onStart()` method, there is no need to check for nullity, just use `mAdapter.startListening();` directly.

Regarding your second question, when you are commenting the view with the id `section_label` and it works, it most likely because your view is set to `match_parent` for both width and height, which in term means that it take all the total space of your view.

There is one more thing that you need to keep in mind regarding your model class. When the Firebase Realtime Database SDK deserializes objects coming from the database, is looking for fields that follow the principles of the JavaBeans and are named accordingly to [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). So a field in your model class should be named `barcode` and not `Barcode`, with the corresponding getter `getBarcode()`. You model class should look like this:

```
public class AddOrderProductList {
    private String barcode;
    private String imageURL;
    private String name;
    private String unit;

    public AddOrderProductList() {}

    public AddOrderProductList(String barcode, String imageURL, String name, String unit) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.name = name;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {return barcode;}
    public String getImageURL() {return imageURL;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getUnit() {return unit;}
}
```

Comment: I've also removed the textview from the XML but it still shows up empty..

Comment: Do this changed as explained above and tell me if it works. Remeber to delete old and add fresh to in order to make it work.

Comment: I've made changes to the model, but still nothing. I've also went into Firestore database to delete and add new entries.

Comment: Please edit your post by adding your database structure and the changed code.

Comment: Done! But like I said, it works in an Activity - so I don't think that part of the code is the issue. That's my own deduction, feel free to prove me wrong.
It isn't loading right when in the fragment.

Comment: Your properties are still capital as I see in your edit but let's admit you changed them. Is your `TabLayout` inside a `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: No it's not inside the AppBarLayout. Do I need one? I tried with it earlier it didn't work as well but I thought I will do without it.

Comment: No, you need to add it inside. It cannot work without it.

Comment: I just added it back but its the same. Still empty

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lMIZEjpFUM&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohe&index=13) and tell me if your .XML file looks like in this video?

Comment: Hey Alex, not yet. My PC is out at the moment for servicing. I'll check it out soon when it's back thanks for following up though!

Comment: Ok. Keep me poested. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Alex, yes my XML look the same as your video. But you commented out the RecyclerView in your fragment, I left mine there in the fragment. 

You were using `CoordinatorLayout`, I was using `ConstraintLayout` for the activity. I also switched it to `CoordinatorLayout` - but still not working.

But I'll take some time today in a while to look through your video again to change my code a bit to match your video.

Comment: OK@HWong Looking forward to hear news from you.

Comment: it works :-)
After changing the way I called fragments to follow your way, I added the onStart and onStop, and it works. Previously, fragment classes were in the same activity class, now it's clearer after I followed your tutorial and moved the fragment to a separate class. Thanks much - AGAIN.

Comment: You're welcome @HWong ! Happy to head that it worked. Cheers!